# Blender 2.49 crashes on startup

Tags: python

I was originally using Blender 2.79, but I need to use 2.49 for import some 3d models from game. Import scripts are only works for 2.49 & Python 2.

So I installed Blender 2.49, Python 2.5.2

When I try to start Blender, it goes to black screen and crash right away.

I've tried GPU Driver update, Install OpenGL Extensions viewer, Install other Python versions (like 2.6.6, 2.6.2), set environment variables, Rebooting, Re-install blender etc.

[image]

This is the only what I got.
I've tried to google about `could not determine argv[0] path`, but I couldn't get a clue.

This is the script what I want to use
http://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=13216

Comment: Might want to supply the script you're using.

Comment: I added link of script

Comment: What operating system are you using? It’s feasible that such an old version might not work on, say, Windows 10 but might run on an old Windows XP - worth a try if you’ve got access to an old OS.